In gld90 protocol what is t=0-4 in a traffic report message
In gld90 protocol what is t=0-4 in a traffic report message:

t=0: ADS-B ICAO addresses
t=1: TIS-B ICAO addresses
t=2: ADS-B self-assigned addresses
t=3: TIS-B track file id

How likely is a name collision between the self-assigned address and track file id?
How likely is a name collision between the two gld90 ICAO addresses?
How likely is a name collision between the two ADS-B addresses?
How likely is a name collision between the two TIS-B addresses?
Can you give me examples of the four types?

As far as I understand, all these questions have been answered in What's the differences and the risk of duplicates, between ADS-B and TIS-B addresses? (inc. ICAO and self-assigned options)
